# running ffmpeg on centos

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I was using ffmpeg for creating video thumbnail.I installed the ffmpeg on windows and run on local server it worked but now i have to run it on hosting server like centos For this i have installed the ffmpeg on server but video thumbnails are not generated .How can i check where i am wrong.My code for ffmpeg on windows is:`exec('ffmpeg -y -i '.$file_path.'  -vcodec mjpeg  -ss 00:00:01  -vframes 1 -an -s 620x440 -f rawvideo '.$image.'',$thumb_stdout, $retval); //This is not generating thumbnail on server. Please help`

Comment: have you tried to run the command manually. Also another source of errors that is common when migrating from a windows environment to a linux environment stems from the fact that the windows file system is case insensitive and the linux filesystem is case sensitive. Check all your paths and ensure that they contain the correct case

Comment: my ffmpeg is intalled in var/www/html/abc.Do i have to give this path on linux evnviroment

Comment: can you please tell me the command to run on terminal to check ffmpeg is working or not

Comment: Possibly although just specifying the full path would work as well ... i.e.  ecec('/var/www/html/abc/ffmpeg .........');

Comment: easiest way to test would be to copy the exec line in your code and replace exec with echo... then you will see exactly what exec would send to the shell to process. you can then copy and past that code into the terminal to see if it will run.

Comment: if i use this path in php file is it correct  exec('/var/www/html/abc/ffmpeg-php-0.6.2 -y -i '.$file_path.'  -vcodec mjpeg  -ss 00:00:01  -vframes 1 -an -s 620x440 -f rawvideo '.$image.'',$thumb_stdout, $retval); ???/

Comment: change exec to echo, the run what the echo outputs in the terminal and bash will tell you what's wrong :)

Comment: echo is not working how to get the output in terminal

Comment: is it outputting something.. when you do echo('/var/www/html/abc/ffmpeg-php-0.6.2 -y -i '.$file_path.' -vcodec mjpeg -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 -an -s 620x440 -f rawvideo '.$image.'',$thumb_stdout, $retval);

Comment: try running `/var/www/html/abc/ffmpeg-php-0.6.2 -y -i /path/to/your/file -vcodec mjpeg -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 -an -s 620x440 -f rawvideo ouputimagename` in the terminal... of course replacing /path/to/your/file with the full path to your file and outputimagename with the image file name you want to output

Comment: don't think I'm going to be able to help you then

Comment: the ouput is -bash /var/www/html/abc/ffmpeg-php-0.6.2 is a directory

Comment: That means that the path you specified is not the executable.... did you install the tool or just download it.

Comment: There are many folders inside ffmpeg-php-0.62. which file i have to call for executing fffmpeg.As in windows there was ffmpeg.exe  which i executed and installed automatically

Comment: type `which ffmpeg` in a terminal and it should let you know where the executable is... if it can't find it then you didn't install it properly

Comment: it is saying no ffmpeg in (usr/bin/sbin.....)

Comment: That means you didn't install it ... you probably just downloaded and unzipped it ... see https://chrisjean.com/install-ffmpeg-and-ffmpeg-php-on-centos-easily/ for instructions on installing.

Comment: I am facing problem during installation when i run run ./configure $$ make it says headers are not found

Comment: Thank you so much .you really helped me @Orangepill I installed it properly ,ran which ffmpeg and exected the same command it worked .Thanks Alot :)